# Ways to speed up numerical integration

Tags: numerical-integration, performance-tuning, numerics

This first code block is just to create the functions I'm considering. Actual problem follows.

```
f[t_, ts_, τ1_, τ2_] := Piecewise[{{Exp[-τ1/(t - ts) - (t - ts)/τ2]/(2 Sqrt[τ1 τ2] BesselK[1, 2 Sqrt[τ1/τ2]]), t > ts}, {0, t < ts}}]
P[α_, β_, Δt_] := (2 - α) β^(2 - α) (β + Δt)^(α - 3)
WTD[α_, β_] := ProbabilityDistribution[P[α, β, Δt], {Δt, 10^-1, 10^3}]

SeedRandom[4]
n = RandomInteger[{2, 20}];
tau = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {n, 2}];
ν = 2.149;
τrise = tau[[1, 2]]/2 Sqrt[ν - Sqrt[ν (ν + 4 Sqrt[tau[[1, 1]]/tau[[1, 2]]])]] // Abs;
τdecay = tau[[-1, 2]]/2 Sqrt[ν + Sqrt[ν (ν + 4 Sqrt[tau[[-1, 1]]/tau[[-1, 2]]])]];
wt = RandomVariate[WTD[1, 6], n];
tmax = 1.1 (τrise + Total@wt + τdecay);
ts[1] := 0
ts[i_] := ts[i - 1] + wt[[i]] - (Sqrt[tau[[i, 1]] tau[[i, 2]]] - Sqrt[tau[[i - 1, 1]] tau[[i - 1, 2]]])
pulses = Table[f[t, ts[i], tau[[i, 1]], tau[[i, 2]]], {i, 1, n}];

Plot[{pulses, Total@pulses}, {t, 0, tmax}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> RandomColor[n]~Join~{Black}, 
  LabelStyle -> Black, FrameTicksStyle -> Black, 
  FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1/6, ImageSize -> 1300, Exclusions -> None, 
  FrameLabel -> {"t", None}, BaseStyle -> 16, 
  Epilog -> {Text[Style["n=" <> ToString[n] <> " pulses", Black, 22], 
     Scaled[{0.94, 0.9}]]}] // Quiet
```

[image]

---

I need to find the arguments $t_1$ and $t_2$ such that in between there is 90% of the total curve's integral, where $t_1$ is the point at which the integral from $0$ to $t_1$ is 5%, and the integral from $0$ to $t_2$ is 95%. Each `pulse` is normalized to unity, and `Total@pulses` can be normalized as well for simplicity so that its integral from zero to infinity is always unity.

With the following code I divide the whole range into smaller chunks $(i,i+step)$, where `step` divides the range in roughly 100 such chunks. [I found this is already faster than full integrations with an increasing upper limit.] I create a discrete version of the cumulative integral in order to use `Nearest` to find starting values for the `FindRoot`s.

```
tstart = AbsoluteTime[];
Round[tmax]
step = If[Round[tmax/100] == 0, 1, Round[tmax/100]]
temp = Monitor[
    Table[{i + step, 
      NIntegrate[Total@pulses, {t, i, i + step}, PrecisionGoal -> 100,
        WorkingPrecision -> 100]}, {i, 0, Round[tmax] - 1}], i]; // Quiet
int = Transpose[{#[[1]], 1/(n step) Accumulate@#[[2]]} &@Transpose[temp]];
ListLinePlot[int, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
 GridLines -> {{}, {0.05, 0.95}}, Epilog -> Point[int]]
nf = Nearest[int[[All, 2]] -> int[[All, 1]]];
AbsoluteTime[] - tstart
```

[image]

> 6.323058

With the starting values, the actual interval from $t_1$ to $t_2$ is quite straightforward:

```
F[tint_?NumberQ] := 1/n NIntegrate[Total@pulses, {t, 0, tint}]
(tint /. FindRoot[F[tint] == 0.95, {tint, First@nf[0.95]}]) - (tint /. FindRoot[F[tint] == 0.05, {tint, First@nf[0.05]}])
```

> 82.0999

It *works*, but this particular `SeedRandom` results in the total computational time about 7 seconds. I encountered instances when it took 30 seconds. The problem is that I need to perform about a million of such simulations, so assuming optimistically it will take on average 10 seconds per iteration, it will last 4 months. With `ParallelTable` in `temp` I get slightly over a factor of two improvement (so optimistically leading to 2 months of computations). I also changed the `Piecewise` in the definition of `f` to `HeavisideTheta/UnitStep` with no improvement whatsoever.

Is there a way to either speed up the integration (I checked various `Methods`, no improvement, including `Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}` – all lead to a longer evaluation; the `PrecisionGoal` and `WorkingPrecision` are set to `100` 'cause with lower values often there was lack of stability and no answer was returned), or to attack it altogether differently to obtain the values of $t_2-t_1$? A tenfold reduction of time would suffice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Should be a bit faster... Long story short: Supply the `Jacobian` of your equation to `FindRoot`, too.

```
ϕ = t \[Function] Evaluate[Total@pulses];
ClearAll[Φ];
Φ[x_?NumericQ] :=    NIntegrate[ϕ[t], {t, 0., x}, PrecisionGoal -> 8];

rhs = 0.05 Φ[tmax];

(*An approximate inverse of Φ*)

tlist = Subdivide[0., tmax, 100];
Ψ = Quiet[
   Interpolation[
     Transpose[{Accumulate[N[ϕ /@ tlist]], tlist}],
     InterpolationOrder -> 1]
   ];
(*Initial guess:*)
x0 = Ψ[rhs];

(*Using Newton's method.The Jacobian of Φ is easy enough to compute!;)*)

sol = FindRoot[Φ[x] == rhs , {x, x0}, 
     Jacobian :> {{ϕ[x]}}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.056017

Test:

```
Φ[x] - rhs /. sol
```

> -1.11022*10^-16

Btw.: There is no point in enforcing 100(!) digits of precision with `PrecisionGoal -> 100` if `FindRoot`'s default `PrecisionGoal` is used (it's about 8, isn't it?).

Comment: Actually, since the `Interpolation` is quite fast, with a sampling dense enough I can then just use `Ψ[0.95] - Ψ[0.05]`.

Comment: If that is sufficiently accurate, then yeah, great!

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, to get the right result, you have to multiply rhs with n in the last line  `sol = FindRoot[\[CapitalPhi][x] == rhs*n, {x, x0}, 
  Jacobian :> {{\[Phi][x]}}] `  since n is the norm of Total@pulses. `NIntegrate[Total@pulses, {t, 0, tmax*2}] `  yields 11.  (NIntegrate to tmax is not sufficient)

Comment: @Akku14 You have a good point there! I completely forgot about the correct scaling. I hope things are fixed by setting `rhs = 0.05 Φ[tmax];` and by removing the normalization in the construction of `Ψ`.

Answer (score 10):

Let NDSolve do the job one time (instead of Integrate many times)

**Edit**  Make it faster. AbsouteTiming for all calculations == 0.015 seconds.

```
(tpw[t_] = Total@pulses;

 gsol = g /. 
   First@NDSolve[{g'[t] == tpw[t], g[0] == 0}, g, {t, 0, 250}];

 norm = gsol[250] ;(*11.*)

{t05 = t /. First@FindRoot[gsol[t] == .05 norm, {t, 0, 150}],
 t95 = t /. First@FindRoot[gsol[t] == .95 norm, {t, 0, 150}]}
) //  AbsoluteTiming

(*   {0.0155646, {4.06347, 128.699}}   *)

NIntegrate[Total@pulses, {t, 0, t05}]/norm
(*   0.05   *)

NIntegrate[Total@pulses, {t, 0, t95}]/norm
(*   0.95   *)

Plot[{1, .05, .95, gsol[t]/norm}, {t, 0, 150}]
```

[image]